# Entity Framework delayed when call SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

I'm using Entity Framework 4 with Ria Service. I have a problem with it, that is when I call SaveChanges it does not submit those changes to database yet, it take a while (which I'm not sure how long does it take) before it actually write that data into the table.

I want to know how can I configure entity framework (or wcf ria) to write data immediately after I call SaveChanged()

Comment: What does it mean take a while?

Comment: @Ladislav: when I call SaveChanges() and its callback method get invoke at client but there's no data in table yet.

Comment: Are there any transactions involved?

Comment: @Ladislav: I don't use any transaction because it call SaveChanges() only once and it only insert 1 record.

Comment: Show the client and server code whith some comments where the problem happens. also how do you monitor db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug on Entity Framework. As far as I can remember it was because I had a trigger on that table.